# how to make duplicate of message and forward it to different user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, message, uimenucontroller

I'm new to iOS, and I'm making a simple chat application. But I have a problem in that I don't know how to make a duplicate of a message and send that message to different user. When I select a message then select the `forward` button I want to create a duplicate message that I then send to a different user.

I have already created a context menu (uimenucontroller) and I added three items (`delete`,  `copy` and `forward`). I have finished the `delete` and `copy` part but I don't know how to do the `forward` part. Please help me.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: You can push the view on forward button with copy that message and on clicking on any user row you can add that copied message to textbox and send it.

Comment: Can you post the context menu code?

Comment: @bhavinramani i'm doing the same but some time when i paste the text on textbox then text get hidden and when i go back and come again the text is their.if i don't go back and click on textbox the box disappear. and also i don't want to send only text i want to send any kind of message like image,videos etc . thats why i want that when i want that when i tab on user's row the message will automatically send not through textbox.